# (Noob) - Simple PHP E-mail form code?

Tags: php

I bought a bootstrap theme just to make a simple site.  It has a contact form on it and the theme creator said to make sure your hosting let's you use php.  I asked my host and they said:

> "You need to add email authentication to the form.
>
> Create an email address in cpanel for use with the form, then use that
>   user name and password to authenticate the email sending from the
>   form.
>
> http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm"

I created the e-mail in cpanel, but unfortunately, I am not knowledgable enough for the next step.  I was hoping someone could help me with the code to get this form working.

This is the email.php code in it's entirety:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = "Message";
$body = "From $name, $email,  \n\n$message";

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

Is there something simple I can add to this to authenticate and make the form work?

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

You could edit your `email.php / html` code to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Send email example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="sender_email" placeholder="Senders email address">
        <input type="text" name="receiver_email" placeholder="Receivers email address">
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send email</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    require_once('send_email_class.php');
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $sender_email = $_POST['sender_email'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $send_email = new send_email_class($sender_email, $receiver_email, $subject, $message);
        $send_email_response = $send_email->send_email();
        echo $send_email_response;
    }
?>
```

and upload the following code as a file called: `send_email_class.php` to your webserver.

```
<?php
    class send_email_class {
        // Class constructor storing variables
        function __construct($sender, $receiver, $subject, $message){
            $this->receiver = $receiver;
            $this->subject = $subject;
            $this->message = $message;
            $this->header = 'From: ' . $sender . '\r\n';
        }

        // Function to send the email
        function send_email(){
            if(mail($this->receiver, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->headers)){
              return 'Mail sent.';
            }else{
              return 'Unable to send mail.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Ofcourse you don't have to enter all those informations from the `form`, you could store some informations like the `$sender_email` variable fixed in your PHP code.

But thats up to you. Hope this helped.

---

**Edit:**

Please replace the content of the `email.php` with the following:

```
<?php
    class email{
        // Class constructor storing variables
        function __construct($sender_email, $sender_name, $message){
            $this->sender = $sender_email;
            $this->sender_name = $sender_name;
            $this->message = $message;
            $this->receiver = 'changeme@email.com';
            $this->subject = 'Email from: ' . $sender_name;
            $this->header = 'From: ' . $sender_email . '\r\n';
        }

        // Function to send the email
        function send_email(){
            if(mail($this->receiver, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->header)){
              return 'Thank you ' . $this->sender_name . ' for sending the email containing the following message: ' . $this->message;
            }else{
              return 'Sorry ' . $this->sender_name . ' a error occured, please try again.';
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $sender_email = $_POST['email'];
        $sender_name = $_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $send_email = new email($sender_email, $sender_name, $message);
        $send_email_response = $send_email->send_email();
        echo $send_email_response;
    }
?>
```

And edit the following code line: `$this->receiver = 'changeme@email.com';`

---

**Final answer:**

After receiving the files, the fix was easy, the ajax been dealing with the handling itself.

mail.php content:

```
<?php
    $receiver = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Email from: ' . $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $header = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'];

    mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the reply.  I am sorry however a lot of this post went over my head.  I would replace my current content of email.php with these?  Do I need to change anything in the html also?

Comment: Thank you so much for continuing to help.  However, I am unsure of what to edit in my html contact form to make it fit your code, Could you take a look?  Here is the html of my form:  https://jsfiddle.net/441czy8f/

Comment: What is supposed to be stored inside the Name input field? Is the email field supposed to contain the receiver email?

Comment: It is a form for users to contact me.  They type their name into the name.  Their e-mail into the e-mail, and then a  message.  It would then hopefully be sent to an email address of mine that I specify (the template creator had us specify OUR email address in the e-mail.php under $to = "myemail@gmail.com";

Comment: Updated my answer and added the solution to the end of my answer.

Comment: I replaced my e-mail.php to your e-mail and put my e-mail address in for the changeme@email.com  The form says "mail sent" - however I don't receive any email on my end.  Is the php you gave me supposed to work with my original html in the fiddle i posted?  Is the problem with authentication like my host said originally?  The host said I need to create an email from my cpanel and use that user name and password to authenticate the email.  This is the part I don't know understand.

Comment: Please replace it using the last code I submitted it is on the bottom of the answer. The response should look like the following: Thank you Name for sending the email containing the following message: Test

Comment: I definitely replaced my email.php with yours.  But when it submits it just says 'Your email has been sent' still.  Here is a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/gDjWdI7.png

Comment: Weird, cause if I submit this code it would look like this: http://helpful.ninja/projects/stackoverflow/ and the test email ive used to reveive is the following trashmail: https://www.byom.de/nachrichten/privatdetekteien?email=test_stack the only difference ive used in this code was the form action, ive been posting the values to the same file as u can see here: http://pastebin.com/qbJppgzR

Comment: Ah! searching through the code I found a javascript that appears to be where "Your mail has been sent" is coming from: updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/441czy8f/1/ - how does this js fit into this?

Comment: I have zipped the whole directory here (removed my personal info).  I will send you a tip on paypal if you could get this working, it's driving me nuts.  Here is the fullwebsite (really small less than 2MB) https://www.dropbox.com/s/12s4u7dh8b5adva/helpwebsite.zip?dl=0

Comment: Replace your email.php code with this and it will work: http://pastebin.com/2jwRGF50 don't forget to edit this line: `$receiver = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';`

Comment: Samr problem unfortunately :(  it says "Your email has been sent." but the email never shows up... is this my hosting ya think?  They did mention that to send e-mail, I need to authenticate it with an email I made in the sites cpanel.  Would buying a different hosting like hostgator fix this?

Comment: Ok I think it IS my hosting! I just tried it on my friend's godaddy hosting as opposed to my cheap hosting and the e-mail was sent and I received it!  Maybe my cheap hosting requires some weird authentication that godaddy doesn't?

Comment: they did tell me "You need to add email authentication to the form.

Create an email address in cpanel for use with the form, then use that user name and password to authenticate the email sending from the form."

Comment: Never heard about tht tbh usually u create a email and use the php is ent